# Fix point of a map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be a map satisfying the following property: there exist $L\in[0,1)$ and positive integer $m\in \mathbb{N}$, s.t., for any $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$, we have $|f^m(x)-f^m(y)|\leq L|x-y|$. Here $f^m(x)=f(f^{m-1}(x))$.

Question: Prove that there exists $x_0\in \mathbb R^n$, s.t., $f(x_0)=x_0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Since $f^m$ is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) in the  complete metric space $\mathbb R^n$, by the [Banach Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), it has a unique fixed point: there exists a unique $x_0\in \mathbb R^n$, such that $f^m(x_0)=x_0$.

Now let $x_1:=f(x_0)$  then
$$f^m(x_1)=f^{m+1}(x_0)=f(f^m(x_0))=f(x_0)=x_1.$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: I don't get it. _Edited to add_: Ahh, now I do $-$ the key is the word _unique_.

Comment: @TonyK Well, that $x_1$ is "another" fixed point of $f^m$. Do you agree?